# Data presentation in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, presentation

At the moment, I´m writing a C# - WPF - application, where I often need to show a few Data out of the database. 
Now, my "problem" is, that I don´t want to use a datagrid, because it is already used very often in my app.

Is there any control to show data to the user "beautiful" instead of a datagrid?

Comment: "Better-looking than a DataGrid" is a highly subjective concept. WPF lets you radically restyle controls to achieve whatever visual experience you desire, but there's no built-in switch you can flip to make your controls, as you mentioned in comments, "more web 2.0-like".

Answer (score 2):

[`ListView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listview.aspx) with a [`GridView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridview.aspx) as [`View`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listview.view.aspx) looks pretty nice by default. (Also there is nothing stopping your from making a nice style for the `DataGrid`)

Comment: A ListView with a GridView? Hm, doesn´t that look pretty much as a DataGrid again?

Comment: @user896692: Somewhat, but it's less plain. How else would you show data than in some kind of grid?

Comment: That´s even that what I don´t know.. don´t you think that nearly every WPF app looks extremely similiar? I want mine to look more "web 2.0 -like", and I don´t know if there are any external controls that don´t look like normal WPF.

Comment: @user896692: I really would not recommend that, there is a good reason why they all look similar: They provide similar functionality and grids are what is best suited for that.

Comment: Did you check out [WPF Themes](http://wpf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WPF%20Themes&referringTitle=Home) to restyle you application. Also it's nothing stopping you from styling every control for your needs, that's one of the big advantages of WPF over winforms.